# Pagination is not working properly in php

Tags: php, pagination

I am trying to make my pagination the way I want. Currently, it is working fine but all the numbers are displaying. Plus the total number is fixed. 
I want to implement pagination in a proper way.
I want to make it dynamic. Mean it should count total pages from the last date that is available in the database. 
**Code**

```
        $joursParPage = 3;
        $joursTotales = '45';
        $pagesTotales = ceil($joursTotales/$joursParPage);
        if(isset($_GET['page']) AND !empty($_GET['page']) AND $_GET['page'] > 0 AND $_GET['page'] <= $pagesTotales) {
           $_GET['page'] = intval($_GET['page']);
           $pageCourante = $_GET['page'];
        } else {
           $pageCourante = 1;
        }
        $depart = ($pageCourante-1)*$joursParPage;



        for($i=$depart;$i<=$pageCourante*3;$i++) {
    ?>

        <h4 class="block-title">
            <span style="margin-right: 0px;">Actualités du <?php echo utf8_encode(strftime('%A %d %B %Y', strtotime('-'.$i.' day'))); ?></span>
        </h4>
        <?php 
        $date = strftime('%Y-%m-%d', strtotime('-'.$i.' day'));
        $videoDer = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM videos WHERE date_video = ? ORDER BY id DESC');
        $videoDer->execute(array($date));
        while($vD = $videoDer->fetch()) { ?>

    <?php }
        $articleDer = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE date_article = ? ORDER BY id DESC');
        $articleDer->execute(array($date));
    while($aD = $articleDer->fetch()) { ?>

    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="lien_page">
    <span class="page_titre"> Pages  </span>
 <?php
  for($l=1;$l<=$pagesTotales;$l++) {
     if($l == $pageCourante) {
        echo '<span class="pageActuelle">'.$l.'</span>';
     } else {
        echo ' <a href="index.php?page='.$l.'" class="lien_page">'.$l.'</a> ';
     }
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Could you show us the final result of your pagination in a screen shot to understand the problem well?

Comment: yes i can http://prntscr.com/hsczcc

Comment: By the way, Stack Overflow, allows you to upload photos into the post. :).

Comment: it was taken in urgent to respond you quickly

Comment: Concentrate on the last loop of your code. Also, you can [**checkout this algorithm**](https://gist.github.com/kottenator/9d936eb3e4e3c3e02598) implementation in JavaScript, it will help you to implement your own in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are doing in a heavy way

Best way is to use `limit` clause instead of for loop to access specific no of records like you are doing.

```
$recordsPerPage = 5;
$currentPage    = (isset($_GET['page]) && $_GET['page'] > 0)?$_GET['page]:1;
if($currentPage == 1){
    $startRecord = 1;
}else{
    $startRecords   = (($currentPage - 1) * $recordsPerPage) + 1 
    // it will be 6 in case of Page=2
    // it will be 11 in case of Page 3
}

$date           = strftime('%Y-%m-%d', strtotime('-'.$i.' day'));
$videoDer       = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM videos WHERE date_video = ? ORDER BY id DESC limit '.$startRecords.', '.$recordsPerPage);
$videoDer->execute(array($date));


// your query looks like
select *
from videos
where date_video = ''
order by id desc
limit 6,5;
```

Comment: I did not get this sir.

Comment: Means, instead of getting all records and then traverse via a for loop, you need to get the starting record and noOfRecords and attach in `limit` clause.

Comment: so what changes can i do in my code. Because i also want to show numbers too.

Comment: Send me your file at ping@naveedramzan.com